# JavaScript, Promises coexisting with callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

How can I improve my third function below to use both functions based on callbacks and functions based on Promises?

The first function is a standard callback implementation of "times 2".

```
function a(i, cb) {
  return cb(null, i * 2);
}

let ans = 
  a(2,
    function(error, result) {
      if (error) console.log('a callback error ' + error.message);
      return result;
    }
  );
console.log('a(2, cb)=' + ans);
```

It arrives at

```
a(2, cb)=4
```

My second function uses Promises for "times 3".

```
function ap(i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return resolve(i * 3); 
  })
}

ap(2)
.then(function(result, error) {
  if (error) console.log('error ' + error.message);
  console.log('ap(2)=' + result);
});
```

It arrives at

```
ap(2)=6
```

The motivation for this question is a piece of code in which I can't seem to get statements to occur in the proper order. I'm trying with this third function to learn how to make functions with callbacks coexist with functions with Promises. This first attempt calls the above callback function and chains the above Promise function next.

```
let ans;
function aap(i) {
  let answer = a(i, function(error, result) {
    if (error) console.log('error ' + error.message);
    return result;
  });
  ap(answer)
  .then(function(result, error) {
    console.log('aap ap callback   result=' + result + '   error=' + error);
    if (error) console.log('error ' + error.message);
    ans = result;
  })
}

aap(2);
console.log('aap(2)=' + ans);
```

It arrives at both

```
aap(2)=null
aap ap callback   result=12   error=undefined
```

The first line looks like a failure. I see from the second line that if only I could control the statement order more effectively, the right answer is available. How best?

Comment: your third function has many problems - the main one being your lack of understanding of asynchronous coding techniques

Comment: You are beating around the bush. Please clearly explain the actual problem.

Comment: I seek to learn the techniques others are using (if they are) to use both functions using callbacks and functions using Promises. The right answer is in the example I've offered, but my inability to control the order of statement execution prevents my using that answer in a program.

Comment: I accept that I lack understanding of asynchronous coding techniques. Some StackOverflow moderators seem to believe that my asking for recommendations on sources to explain that material is inappropriate use of StackOverflow, so I've drawn up an example hoping it'll get me help I need. I want to use the site as intended; I seek some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating `error` handling to second parameter of `.then()` , returning `ap` from `aap` , setting `ans` as `let ans = aap(2)`

```js
function a(i, cb) {
  return cb(null, i * 2);
}

function ap(i) {
  return Promise.resolve(i * 3);
}

function aap(i) {
  let answer = a(i, function(error, result) {
    if (error) console.log("error " + error.message);
    return result;
  });
  return ap(answer)
    .then(function(result, error) {
      console.log("aap ap callback   result=" + result);
      return result;
    }, function(e) {
      if (e) console.log("e " + e.message);
      return e
    })
}

let ans = aap(2);

ans.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  return res
}, function err(e) {
  console.log(e)
});

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: I like this solution. I notice that the result of the last line is published first, `Promise { <pending> }`. Is there a way to make ans hold res at this point?

Comment: @BaldEagle _"Is there a way to make ans hold res at this point?"_ `ans` returns `Promise` having fulfilled value `res` , `console.log(ans);` included at Answer to demonstrate that `ans` is defined as a `Promise` object

Answer (score 0):

@guest271314 did a great job of answering the question. Further, they gave me the tools I needed to create a useful answer to a follow-on question. My original post hinted lightly at a follow-on question to come; it would have asked for techniques to create function apa(i) (which would call ap() first and chain it to a() (the reverse of the question asked above).

Here's what I got

```
function apa(i) {
  ap(i)
  .then(function(result, error) {
    if (error) console.log('error ' + error.message)
    else return a(result, function(error2, result2) {
      if (error2) console.log('error ' + error2.message)
      else console.log('apa(' + i + ')=' + result2);
    });
  });
}

apa(2);
```

It arrives at

```
apa(2)=12
```

If anyone cares to post better techniques for comingling functions with callbacks and functions with Promises in asynchronous environments, I'd love to read about it. By demonstration, I conclude it is possible to do.